# Is human spritesheets for game development allowed?

Tags: fiqh, image, game

Assalamu'alaykum 
I Just want to ask, I am a stand alone indie game developer (programmer+designer+etc).
I heard there are a lot of hadiths that told us not to draw animate being, and the problem is actually simple:

I do the character spriting (with mouse, sometime graphic tablet) for the game and I always create it retro style like final fantasy, of course there will be some face&body features that can't be shown/imperfect in the game sprite **(no mouth, no nose, limbs too small, etc)** because of the small dimension (I usually use 32x32 pix per image). In other words, **It's far from the actual being**.

and for the question:
**Is creating human spritesheet for game I stated earlier allowed in Islam?**

btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your question is answered in my answer here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/105/is-game-development-programming-prohibited?rq=1

Comment: As someone who is not Muslim, but interested in game design and impressed with Islamic geometric artwork, I think I’d rather like to see a game with geometric sprites that represent characters. A thought, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I've read a number of fatawa (no references handy) that interpret the prohibition on drawing animate objects to refer to creating *physical* representations thereof.  When the drawing is completely ephemeral such as a digital image on a computer, which only exists as a "drawing" when the computer both interprets and displays it as one, it wouldn't fall under that prohibition.

Comment: so as long I "draw" them _digitally_, whether with mouse or graphic tablet, it's okay? let's just say I'm going to create **human 3D model** or **another detailed (larger dimension) human game sprite** for the game (It will be cartoon-like though) in my computer, it's still okay?

Comment: @user4546 basically, yeah, so long as you're not drawing on paper first and scanning them in, or printing them out when you're done, they wouldn't really count as "making images" in this case.

Comment: +1 this is the correct opinion about this issue